# Has anyone found a download for a Mountain Lion resembling Dock theme?

Tags: dock, themes, macos

Mountain Lion has a SWEET new Dock look that I'd love to replicate into my Lion install. Has anyone found a download link for any kind of fan art resembling it accurately, yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite right, but this can be installed with [Dock Library](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/26972/dock-library) and is off by a mere few pixels.

http://cl.ly/0B271a1g3Y302E0t0w41